# windows 10 constantly at ~50% cpu with no apparant cause

Tags: windows-10, cpu

This morning I started my laptop and noticed it was very loud, task manager said it was continuously around 50% cpu usage with windows defender eating up most of (which is apparently a common issue). After a frustratingly long time of trying to figure out how to fix it, I ended up disabling windows defender and installing McAfee, and now windows defender doesn't appear in the task manager anymore. But I'm still at a near-constant 50% cpu usage, even without anything open aside from task manager, and I can't figure out why. Yesterday everything was just fine - I could video call without the fans becoming audible no problem.

I really don't know what to do, I'm not very tech-savvy and I've spent the past 2 hours gently weeping onto my laptop trying to figure out how to get this thing to work.

laptop is Dell Inspiron with processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz   2.90 GHz

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the Event Log service is writing stuff to disk. I suggest checkout the logs with Event Viewer. // What’s `TrueColorALS`?

Comment: @DanielB no clue what TrueColorALS is, it's part of TrueColor which has always been there so I always assumed it's got something to do with like...correctly portraying color on your screen or something.

Comment: Did you get around to checking Event Viewer yet?

Comment: my apologies for the late update, I wanted to make sure that the solution had stabilized. checking Event Viewer, there were dozens of error reports per second from TrueColorALS, so I repaired it via Control Panel and then killed it from the task manager and bam. CPU drops to normal levels. no changes since then so i assume that must've been it. my brother's laptop also wound up having the exact same issue, and repairing true color fixed it (even before messing with windows defender or anything). thank you for the help!

Comment: [Event Viewer Screenshot regarding TrueColorALS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khulv.png) Had the same issue, just to add an image

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue on my Dell laptop.
More than 50% CPU in Idle state.

In Task manager I saw "TrueColorALS" and multiple (~10) instances of "igfxext Module".
Once I closed TrueColorALS, all igfxext Module instances except 1 disappeared and CPU utilization dropped to 2%.

So I removed TrueColor from Startup application and now my laptop is back to life.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, all the CPU usage values add up to almost the reported 53% figure. So one of the processes visible is likely to blame.

From the active processes, we can deduce that the root cause may be some DCOM problem. Some operation is likely failing and retried at a very high rate. This causes errors in Windows Event Log which results in disk usage which in turn is scanned by McAfee.

Because errors are apparently getting logged, you can use Event Viewer to investigate. It may directly or indirectly list the cause.

---

You indicate that `TrueColorALS.exe` was to blame. Its installation may have been damaged by a Windows update or something the like.

Answer (score 0):

Just the tasks you have shown in your screenshot sum up to a total usage of 45.5%, it is feasible that the rest of your tasks make up the other 7.5% to get to the 53% figure you see here. As to why these regular processes are taking up such a large amount of usage, there may be power saving settings which reduce the performance of your CPU.

You can check if this is the case by right clicking the battery icon on your taskbar and then left clicking "Power Options." From there you can enable high performance mode if it is not already enabled, though this will reduce the battery life of your laptop.

If you are already on high performance mode, you can try clicking "Change plan settings" next to it and then "Change advanced power settings," and verify that "Processor power management > Maximum processor state" is set to 100%.

Comment: I added another possibility if changing the power plan did not work, try checking that if you've already looked at this answer.

Comment: I've switched to high performance mode, max processor state is indeed set to 100%. thank you for the answer! after restarting my laptop, nothing has changed - fans are still whirring and the numbers seem to be the same. I'd be surprised if battery settings were the issue because it's been a long while since I last changed them, and there have been no problems until now.

Comment: Does the issue still occur when your Memory consumption is below 5.1 GB as it is in the screenshot? It could be aggressively writing to page files and if you have a slow hard drive it would slow it down, although I'm not sure high CPU usage would be a symptom of that.

Comment: In the other screenshot, we can see that the CPU is already running at maximum turbo frequency. So that’s not the problem.

Comment: Does the issue occur when you boot into safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues of a similar kind and went through a process of disabling non Microsoft programs of which I had about 24.

My cpu was always 51%+ even at startup with nothing else open.

I isolated the problem to TrueColorALS and uninstalled the program.

Now at startup once it settles down my cpu is at 1%.

Hope it helps someone, it was bugging me for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked back at this and noticed that I am running the same processor as the opening poster. That cpu profile usage is about what I was having with TrueColorALS installed.

At the moment with TrueColorALS uninstalled and a fair amount open I am at 3-6%

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).